# SQL Server 2008 Cursor when are table values loaded?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, cursor

While using cursor in SQL Server 2008 ,at which statement the values from tables are loaded into the cursor?

```
declare @sname nvarchar(50)

declare  cur1 cursor
for
select sname   from tstudent 


open cur1
FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @sname
print  @sname 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
      FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @sname  
      if @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            print  @sname     
 END
CLOSE cur1
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `OPEN` a cursor, the cursor gets populated from DB using the query specified in `DECLARE` statement. More on this at [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190500.aspx)